# input filld not getting while typing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

in  input  tag  while i placed  value attribute in it   it  not getting input  from keybord  not showing    input

```
import React from 'react'

class Postform extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'helo',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    bio: '',
  };

  changeHandler = (event) => {};

  submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <div classNam=" form-group ">
            <label htmlFor="name">Enter your name </label>
            <input
              placeholder="Enter your name"
              id="name"
              className="form-control"
              name="name"
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
              value="hello"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info">
            submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Postform;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the input `value` to be `hello` this means that it will stay `hello` no matter what.

To make the input `value` dynamic you going to need to set the value from the `state` of your component as the input `value`.

This means that you also going to have to update the `state` when the input `value` changes using the `changeHandler`.

Lets start from the input

```
// Always read the input value from state
// and when the input value changes call this.changeHandler
<input onChange={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.name} />
```

Then the `changeHandler`

```
changeHandler = (event) => {
  // The input value has been changed, get the value from
  // event.target.value and set it as state.
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
};
```

Now the `state` will be updated and the component will `re-render` the input with the current `state.name` as the value